# QEMU Linux Kernel Panic With BusyBox

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, busybox, panic

I am following [this](https://ops.tips/notes/booting-linux-on-qemu/) guide to run a minimal linux kernel on top of QEMU, and keep running into the same issue. I have also tried other similar tutorials and end up with the same panic. Since the panic seems to be related to the `/init` script, I have tried swapping this out with a (statically linked) binary but still end up with the panic. The only thing I have done differently from the tutorial is using the latest stable version of BusyBox (currently 1.34.1). The text of the panic is [here](https://pastebin.com/UW5m7tw9) and linked below. If anyone has any insight on this that would be great!

```
Linux version 5.15.0+ (michael@tree) (gcc (Gentoo Hardened 10.3.0-r2 p3) 10.3.0, GNU ld (G1
Command line: console=ttyS0
x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
signal: max sigframe size: 1040
BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000007fdffff] usable
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000007fe0000-0x0000000007ffffff] reserved
BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffc0000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
SMBIOS 2.8 present.
DMI: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS d55cb5a 04/01/2014
tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
tsc: Detected 3992.482 MHz processor
last_pfn = 0x7fe0 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT
found SMP MP-table at [mem 0x000f5c80-0x000f5c8f]
RAMDISK: [mem 0x07cf6000-0x07fdffff]
Zone ranges:
  DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
  DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x0000000007fdffff]
  Normal   empty
Movable zone start for each node
Early memory node ranges
  node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
  node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000007fdffff]
Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000007fdffff]
On node 0, zone DMA: 1 pages in unavailable ranges
On node 0, zone DMA: 97 pages in unavailable ranges
On node 0, zone DMA32: 32 pages in unavailable ranges
Intel MultiProcessor Specification v1.4
MPTABLE: OEM ID: BOCHSCPU
MPTABLE: Product ID: 0.1
MPTABLE: APIC at: 0xFEE00000
Processor #0 (Bootup-CPU)
IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 0, version 32, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
Processors: 1
[mem 0x08000000-0xfffbffff] available for PCI devices
clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 764551s
Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 31968
Kernel command line: console=ttyS0
Dentry cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
Memory: 114084K/130552K available (4097K kernel code, 768K rwdata, 484K rodata, 532K init,)
SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
NR_IRQS: 4352, nr_irqs: 48, preallocated irqs: 16
Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x73193cf9da3, max_idle_ns: 8s
Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 7984.96 BogoMIP)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 0
CPU: AMD QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+ (family: 0x6, model: 0x6, stepping: 0x3)
Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Spectre V2 : Spectre mitigation: kernel not compiled with retpoline; no mitigation availab!
Speculative Store Bypass: Vulnerable
Performance Events: PMU not available due to virtualization, using software events only.
clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 76450417851000s
futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early
platform rtc_cmos: registered platform RTC device (no PNP device found)
Unpacking initramfs...
workingset: timestamp_bits=62 max_order=15 bucket_order=0
Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
random: get_random_bytes called from init_oops_id+0x2f/0x40 with crng_init=0
sched_clock: Marking stable (333996480, 16836404)->(354705829, -3872945)
Freeing initrd memory: 2984K
Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 532K
Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 8192k
Freeing unused kernel image (text/rodata gap) memory: 2044K
Freeing unused kernel image (rodata/data gap) memory: 1564K
Run /init as init process
Failed to execute /init (error -13)
Run /sbin/init as init process
Run /etc/init as init process
Run /bin/init as init process
Run /bin/sh as init process
Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. Se.
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 5.15.0+ #1
Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS d55cb5a 04/01/2014
Call Trace:
 <TASK>
 dump_stack+0x20/0x22
 panic+0xd0/0x246
 ? rest_init+0x90/0x90
 kernel_init+0xfc/0x100
 ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
 </TASK>
Kernel Offset: disabled
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: No working init found.  Try passing init= option to k-
QEMU 6.0.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) quit
```

Additionally, I have actually tried very similar steps on a completely different computer, so I'm pretty sure there is something I am missing in-general. Both machines are running Gentoo but I have successfully used QEMU to emulate other existing operating systems on both devices (so I think I can exclude a missing kernel configuration)?

Answer (score 0):

Add execute mode to `/init` file before you build CPIO initramfs:

```
chmod +x <path-to-your-initrd-root>/init
```

Comment: Thanks! But I did do this (as listed in the tutorial, which I followed exactly)

Comment: Permissions of init are `-rwxr-xr-x 1 michael michael  139 Nov  2 21:32 init`

Comment: @MichaelHoefler: this is just a guess, but I could see the kernel refusing to run `init` if it's not owned by root.

Comment: @sj95126 still no luck :(

Comment: @MichaelHoefler: also make sure that all the directory path components are owned by root and only writable by root, including `/`. Beyond that, I don't have any other suggests except digging through the kernel source